# SQL - Why does Rank in Full Text Search change after Service restarted?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

I'm having some problem with the rank in full text search.
I've updated the SQL to the latest build (11.0.7001.0).
I ran the below query and got 108 records.

After restarting the service "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)", it still returns 108 records.

After restarting the service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)", the query returns only 100 records.

I'll have to rebuild the full-text catalog in order to get the same number of records as previous, which is 108 records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
    SELECT *COLUMNS*
    FROM TABLE
    INNER JOIN FreeTextTable (TABLE, INDEXEDCOLUMN, N'"Sabariah Mohamed Ali" or "Ali Mohamed Sabariah"', 100) as KEY_TABLE ON TABLE.INDEX = KEY_TABLE.[KEY]  
    WHERE KEY_TABLE.rank > 30) as TABLE_1

    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
    SELECT *COLUMNS*
    FROM TABLE
    INNER JOIN Containstable (TABLE, INDEXEDCOLUMN, N'"*Sabariah" or "Sabariah*" 
    or "*Mohamed" or "Mohamed*"', 100) as KEY_TABLE on TABLE.INDEX = 
    KEY_TABLE.[KEY]  
    WHERE KEY_TABLE.rank > 30) as TABLE_1
) as TABLE_2
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this ` WHERE KEY_TABLE.rank > 30` condition? Are you trying to get only top matching records or what?

Comment: Yes. It’s to get the top 100 relevant records